# Iterate through API response and display

Tags: jquery, html, api

I have this API:  https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=supercars&apiKey=[MyApiKey]

I'd like to create a view that displays them with some information. I have to iterate on the `articles` array.

I'd like to replicate the api's info in my views tag. How can I do that? 
I can access the single info, but can't replicate all the news.
With this syntax only the "Lamborgini Sian" news gets shown.

```js
var result;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=supercars&apiKey=[MyApiKey]", function(result) {
    console.log(result.totalResults);
    $(".title").text(result.articles[1].title);
    if (result.status == 'ok') {
      for (var i in result.totalResult) {
        $(".title").text(result.articles[i].title);
      }
    } else {
      window.alert("An error has occured");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="articlesnum"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="title"></div>
  <!--
  <p class="p1">
    <div class="author1"></div> 
  </p>
  <p class="p2"></p>
  -->
</div>
```

Comment: Putting your private API key in a public post is really not a smart move. I've edited it out for you. If you want help with this please edit the question to include a sample of the response format.

Comment: where are you setting the content ?

Comment: @mrid I'm setting it in a view called news. Using codeigniter if it helps.

Comment: You're not dynamically creating info divs for each entry, are you ?? Your code is just updating a single div.

Comment: Basically yes... And I don't know how to do it with json  and API... I thought that "it would get it", but since the behaviour is this it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=supercars&apiKey=[MyApiKey]", show)
});
```

where show is something like shown below

NOTE: They return 20 results at a time so count page = i+20 (and test i*20 <= totalResults)

The trick is the use of backtics (`....`) to make a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

the `${varName}` can then be dropped into the template

```js
// remove THIS result when implementing
var result = {"status":"ok","totalResults":3,
"articles":[
{"source":{"id":"business-insider","name":"Business Insider"},"author":"Aj Caldwell and Matthew DeBord","title":"We spent a day driving the 2020 Nissan GT-R to see if it has the qualities of a good daily driver","description":"The GT-R is one of Nissan's most powerful and icon cars. Nissan advertises it as a supercar you can drive every day. While it may be limited in seating capacity and fuel economy, it has great storage and is comfortable enough to be a daily driver. Visit Busin…","url":"https://www.businessinsider.com/road-test-2020-nissan-gt-r-review-daily-driver-supercar-2019-8","urlToImage":"https://amp.businessinsider.com/images/5d5d6c2dcd97842a68678463-1920-960.jpg","publishedAt":"2019-08-29T13:00:00Z","content":"The following is a transcript of the video.\r\n Matt DeBord: And you'll see, when we floor it, you see it takes a little while to get up to speed there? You see that? \r\n Today, I'm testing out one of the world's most iconic supercars: the Nissan GT-R. I'm Matt … [+7968 chars]"},
{"source":{"id":null,"name":"Cnet.com"},"author":"Sean Szymkowski","title":"Lamborghini Sian is an electrified bull with 819 hp - Roadshow","description":"Lamborghini is using hybrid technology to create faster, more-powerful supercars.","url":"https://www.cnet.com/roadshow/pictures/lamborghini-sian-hybrid-supercar-reveal-frankfurt/","urlToImage":"https://cnet3.cbsistatic.com/img/ZkfyCWQq3850A9R57mZxYxLmAxo=/2019/09/03/88903d67-acfb-4ca9-a26e-27d096dd449e/lambo-ogi2.jpg","publishedAt":"2019-09-03T14:43:21Z","content":"Under the striking and jagged sheetmetal is a traditional V12 engine, but rather than a lithium-ion battery that is often the norm, Lamborghini said it's instead installed the first supercapacitor to operate in a hybrid powertrain."},
{"source":{"id":null,"name":"Cnet.com"},"author":"Roadshow staff","title":"2019 Frankfurt Motor Show: Roadshow's favorite debuts - Roadshow","description":"Wild concepts, frugal EVs and high-power supercars come together on our list of Frankfurt's best debuts.","url":"https://www.cnet.com/roadshow/news/best-of-2019-iaa-frankfurt-motor-show/","urlToImage":"https://cnet3.cbsistatic.com/img/eTEEZvgDnRRehWar9SuK9KeWQgA=/2019/09/03/166a6950-6f28-4992-b91f-a11463bbeeb6/ogi-mb.jpg","publishedAt":"2019-09-11T09:58:33Z","content":"Mercedes-Benz\r\nOnce every two years, the Frankfurt Motor Show earns its reputation as one of the biggest auto shows on the planet. Hundreds of manufacturers spread thousands of cars across the sprawling Messe Frankfurt am Main. While there's never a shortage … [+7139 chars]"}
]}


// you only need this function
function show(result) {
  if (result.status == 'ok') {
    let html = [];
    $.each(result.articles, function(_, article) {
      html.push(`<div>
                   <h3 class="title">${article.title}</h3>
                   <img src="${article.urlToImage}"/>
                   <p class="desc">${article.description}<br/>
                   <span class="author">${article.author}</span></p>
                 </div>`);
    });
    $("#articles").html(html)
  }
}


$(function() { 

// replace
show(result);
// with 
// $.getJSON("https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=supercars&apiKey=[MyApiKey]", show)});

});
```

```css
.author {
  font-size: xx-small;
  color: green;
}

#articles img { height : 150px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="articles"></div>
```

Comment: It's not working not with the "var result... show(result)" syntax, neither with the function call..

Comment: I did removed them. I tried just as you wrote in your comment. I triple checked to be sure...

Comment: <script>
function show(result) {
  var div = document.getElementById("articles");
  if (result.status == 'ok') {
    const articles = result.articles;
    let html = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.totalResults; i++) {
      html.push(`<div>
                   <p class="title">${articles[i].description}</p>
                   <p class="author1">${articles[i].author}</p>
                 </div>`);
    }
    div.innerHTML=html.join("");
  }
}
$(function() { $.getJSON("https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=supercars&apiKey=[myapikey]", show)});
</script>

With my right key obv.

Comment: Now it's perfectly working on my environment too! Thank you very much for the help! You used the .html which I didn't know and it's kind of a game changer in my json culture! xD Thanks again!

Comment: Did you see the image I added :)

Comment: I missed that! I ran the code before you added it and then checked on my environment :(
EDIT: If you mean in the code, yes I saw that, nice touch, but I don't know if you added a "custom" image in the running code...

Comment: Nono. Just showing what is returned from the server

Comment: Yes, tried it right now! So, just to see if I completely understand it. You basically created a standard layout in the script and then you assign it to a tag. Very basically (and badly) explained.
EDIT: not a tag, a class or an id...

Comment: See my updated description. I am using template literals to build the HTML